# Google Cloud Storage Error on Upload - strpos(): Empty needle

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

When uploading a file to Google Cloud Storage (through my app running on app engine) I get the following PHP warning

```
Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/ext/cloud_storage_streams/CloudStorageStreamWrapper.php on line 168
```

I've used `<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>` as per the official guide and then done a basic move

```
$gs_name = $_FILES["uploaded_files"]['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($gs_name, "gs://my_bucket/new_file.ext");
```

Does anyone know why this is and can someone help resolve this?

Comment: Can you specify the SDK version you are using and/or post the 2-3 lines above and below line 168 from that file? Pulling 1.8.8 and 1.8.9 sdks I do not see strpos() on line 168 or near it.

Answer (score 4):

The same problem... Looks like a bug, in the local (latest) version of SDK different code.
As a workaround I use `copy($_FILES["uploaded_files"]['tmp_name'], "gs://my_bucket/new_file.ext")` + `unlink($_FILES["uploaded_files"]['tmp_name'])`, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Needle is what the PHP strpos function calls its first parameter (search for a needle in a haystack).  The value of the $gs_name variable is empty.  The cause is likely some difference in the upload form.

Try going back a step in [PHP Direct uploads to Google Cloud Storage via HTTP POST](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/#direct_uploads_to_google_cloud_storage_via_http_post) and temporarily change your PHP upload handler back to:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

The output will probably differ from what is expected, and may indicate which part of the above mentioned form is responsible.

Comment: I did that, it is as expected. No problem here